# Airflow test a python function used in ```PythonOperator```/```ShortCircuitOperator```

Tags: python, airflow, python-unittest, airflow-2.x

how do you unit test a python function used in `PythonOperator`/`ShortCircuitOperator`?
given a project structure as such:

```
airflow/
│
├── dags/
│   ├── my_dag.py
├── tests/
│   ├── test_my_dag.py
```

in the file `test_my_dag.py` - is it possible to make a test as such:

```
@mock.patch('my_function.my_variable', "some_value")
def test_my_function(self):
    from dags.my_dag import my_function
    assert my_function()==False
```

pytest is unable to import `my_function` and I can’t find any examples